# процент для каждого блока работает но насчет реализации сомневаюсь

Tags: javascript, инспекция-кода

```js
const percentSpan = document.querySelectorAll('.percent')
class Calc {
  constructor(percent, block) {
      this.percent = percent
      this.block = block
    }
    * calculate() {
      for (let i = 0; i <= this.percent; i++) {
        yield this.block.textContent = i
      }
    }
}
const percent = [50, 66, 12, 33]
const calcArr = [...percentSpan].map((elem, i) => {
  return new Calc(percent[i], elem).calculate()
})

let inter = setInterval(() => {
  let next = 0
  for (let key of calcArr) {
    next = key.next()
    if (next.value == Math.max(...percent)) {
      clearInterval(inter)
    }
  }
}, 100);
```

```html
<span class="percent"></span>
<span class="percent"></span>
<span class="percent"></span>
<span class="percent"></span>
```

Comment: и те кто исправит серые пробелы дайте знать как это сделать самому после тега code они появляются не магу удалить

Comment: ты сделал так как хотел или что-то должно быть иначе, не совсем понятно

Comment: @AndreyFreiz нужны были подсчет процентов для каждого блока я реализовал так но насчет правильности реализации не уверен

Comment: @Armen под "правильностью реализации" ты подразумеваешь следование лучшим практикам в написании кода и наилучшей оптимизации твоего решения?

Comment: @sergeyGlazirin да

Comment: я не совсем понял идею, которую ты хотел реализовать, попробуй ее словами описать

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1140081/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be-%d1%83%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%be%d1%81%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%82-0-%d0%b4%d0%be-%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd/1140103#1140103 - хмм?

Comment: @Grundy каждый блок загружается.. на верстке есть круглые поля а внутри проценты. То есть при прокрутке в видимую часть должен появится эффект загрузки процентов для каждого блока разные надеюсь ясно объяснил?

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME спс глянул вроде по компактнее